# Any Way To Compress This To Decrease Load Time

Tags: php

I need this compressed a lot more or be somewhat better so I can decrease load time. This has slowed down load time to about 15 seconds more then it used to be o.0 I need it more compact to decrease load time. Any recommendations?

Code I dont rlly need compressed they are just here so you know whats going on:

```
$dllinks = array($l720p1, $l720p2, $l720p3, $l720p4, $l720p5, $l720p6, $l720p7, $l720p8, $l720p9, $l720p10, $l720p11, $l720p12, $l720p13, $l720p14, $l720p15, $l720p16, $l720p17, $l720p18, $l720p19, $l720p20);

foreach ($Result as $r) {
        $name = $r['name'];
        $rating = $r['rating'];
        $imdbid = $r['imdbid'];
        $genre1 = $r['genre1'];
        if(!empty($r['genre2'])){ $genre2 = '- '.$r['genre2']; }
        $year = $r['year'];
        $plot = $r['plot'];
        $views = $r['views'];
        $downloads = $r['downloads'];
        $seasons = $r['seasons'];
        $l720p1 = $r['l720p1'];
        $l720p2 = $r['l720p2'];
        $l720p6 = $r['l720p6'];
        $l1080p1 = $r['l1080p1'];
        $l1080p2 = $r['l1080p2'];
    }
```

...

Code I need Compressed:

```
if(empty($dllinks[0])) { $dl720p1 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p1 = $l720p1; };
    if(empty($dllinks[1])) { $dl720p2 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p2 = $l720p2; };
    if(empty($dllinks[2])) { $dl720p3 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p3 = $l720p3; };
    if(empty($dllinks[3])) { $dl720p4 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p4 = $l720p4; };
    if(empty($dllinks[4])) { $dl720p5 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p5 = $l720p5; };
    if(empty($dllinks[5])) { $dl720p6 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p6 = $l720p6; };
    if(empty($dllinks[6])) { $dl720p7 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p7 = $l720p7; };
    if(empty($dllinks[7])) { $dl720p8 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p8 = $l720p8; };
    if(empty($dllinks[8])) { $dl720p9 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p9 = $l720p9; };
    if(empty($dllinks[9])) { $dl720p10 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p10 = $l720p10; };
    if(empty($dllinks[10])) { $dl720p11 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p11 = $l720p11; };
    if(empty($dllinks[11])) { $dl720p12 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p12 = $l720p12; };
    if(empty($dllinks[12])) { $dl720p13 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p13 = $l720p13; };
    if(empty($dllinks[13])) { $dl720p14 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p14 = $l720p14; };
    if(empty($dllinks[14])) { $dl720p15 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p15 = $l720p15; };
    if(empty($dllinks[15])) { $dl720p16 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p16 = $l720p16; };
    if(empty($dllinks[16])) { $dl720p17 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p17 = $l720p17; };
    if(empty($dllinks[17])) { $dl720p18 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p18 = $l720p18; };
    if(empty($dllinks[18])) { $dl720p19 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p19 = $l720p19; };
    if(empty($dllinks[19])) { $dl720p20 = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p20 = $l720p20; };
```

Update: Trying to do:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) { 
    if(empty(${'dllinks' . [$i]})) {
        ${'dl720p' . $i} = 'example.com';
    } else {
        ${'dl720p' . $i} = ${'l720p' . $i};
    }
}
```

But its giving me so many error so many its hard for me to open the rror_log cause its flooding!

Comment: don't you mean decrease? and i have no idea what that is suppose to be doing

Comment: @Dagon the updated post should make it easier to understand what its doing

Comment: Btw, The variable = variable's in the else{} is very much needed so I can determine if its a example.com output I should get or a mysql output

Comment: You can increase the load time by setting `set_time_limit(100); // for 100 seconds`  in your php code [Know more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). But I am not sure this is what you desire?

Comment: Definitely not @e3ey

Comment: @Kyubeh2435436 Well you said **increase load time.**

Comment: Oops, I meant decrease

Comment: The code you need "compressed" does not affect the running time very much. Even if you find a way to make it run faster (which is almost impossible), it probably takes a couple of milliseconds to run (or less). If you need to make your script run faster, this **is not** the code you should improve. Check your database queries, the code that accesses the file system or uses remote APIs, this is where the lag is.

Comment: even so is there a way to compress it a bit like do soemthing like
foreach($i = 1; $dllinks[$i]; $i++){
  Some CHecking Code Here? Not Sure What I would Put Here
 } any ideas?

Comment: Maybe:
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
  if(empty($dllinks[$i])) { $dl720p.$i = 'http://example.com'; } else { $dl720p.$i = $l720p.$i; }
 }

Comment: @Joci93 Seems like its giving me alot of errors so many that when I try to view the error_log it takes ages to load cant even see what error is going on right now

Comment: Ok the error is a SHIT TON of: undefined variable: dl720p

Comment: One of the problems is definitely: $dl720p.$i thats impossible I need to do: ${'dl720p' . $i}

Comment: the for loop should start from $i = 0 and end to $i = 20, else it will give notice offset error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something like this

```
$dllinks = array('l720p1' => $l720p1, 'l720p2' => $l720p2, 'l720p3' => $l720p3, 'l720p4' => $l720p4...);
```

Than you could do iteration:

```
foreach ($dllinks as $varName => $value) {
    $varName2 = 'd'.$varName;

    if (empty($value)) {
        $$varName2 = 'http://example.com';
    } else {
        $$varName2 = $value;
    }
}
```

Or better, use array keys instead of separate variables:

```
foreach ($dllinks as &$value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        $value = 'http://example.com';
    }
}

...

echo "<a href='{$dllinks['l720p1']}'>Visit l720p1</a>";
```

Comment: Just a question is the extra $'s and random & in last codeblock on purpose?

Comment: @Kyubeh2435436 extra `$` makes variable value to be call to same name variable (`$a = 'b', $$a will call $b variable`). `&` means you will be changing array element, not it's copy that is made for array.

Comment: @Kyubeh2435436 You are assigning value to `$$varName2`, so in the end it means you assign `example.com` to variable that has same name as array key (e.g. if key is `l720p1`, `$varName2` will be `dl720p1` and `$$varName2 = 'example.com'` will be same as `$dl720p1 = 'example.com'`

Comment: Hmm, Okay but in the example 2 in the echo I need something like this: ${'l720p' . $i} how can I add the .$i bit to this?

Comment: Also if I use example 2, do I need to edit my $dllinks array like you did or is that just for example 1?

Comment: @Kyubeh2435436 You will use same array structure for both examples. In second example you will output array elements, not separate variables, so instead of `${'l720p' . $i}` you will use `$dllinks['l720p'.$i]`

Comment: Example 2 works fine then, But when I try echo $$varName2 in example 1 it doesnt work and gives these errors: http://pastebin.com/znURq72f

Comment: @Kyubeh2435436 Example demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2d27b627fcd71cbaa36c86eaa96c78adcf585259

Comment: Thx but example 1 does the job great for me. Didnt do any improvements in performance but who knows. But thanks doe